# Nova 3 freedom not save progress

Tags: nova

How do I save and restore progress for N.O.V.A. on my Motorola android?

I have tried everything I can figure out but there doesn't seem to be a way to save my progress. So I've only been able to make it through 2 levels before I run out of playing time and then next time I have to start over.

I'm sure it will be obvious once someone tells me, but currently it is very frustrating.